# Summing Columns for values present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a list of football teams, and the number of players they have. I want to take the sum of all the players that play in a team within the premier league. All the teams in the premier league are in the prem_league df, and the number of players a team has is in a no_players df, under a 'players' heading.

How do I sum the column 'players' if the the team they play for is present in the prem_league df?

Example dataframes -

```
no_players:               prem_league:
  Team   players            Teams      Position
ManUtd      23              ManUtd        2nd
Chelsea     45              Spurs         3rd
Everton     20              Chelsea       4th

Total = 45 + 23 = 68
```

Comment: `no_players.loc[no_players["Team"].isin(prem_league["Teams"]), "players"].sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pd.Index.intersection`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) if `Team` and `Teams` are index of dataframes.

```
idx = no_players.index.intersection(prem_league.index)
no_playeres.loc[idx,'players'].sum()
```

If they are not index then use [**`pd.Series.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to create a boolean mask, then use boolean indexing.

```
m = no_players['Team'].isin(prem_league['teams'])
np_players.loc[m, 'players'].sum()
```